# She looks best or Looks the best in this sentence: "She looks ________ in bright, vibrant colors, like red and pink"?

Tags: articles, superlatives

Do I have to put "the best" in this sentence:
"She looks best in bright, vibrant colors, like red and pink." if not so why?

This is from the Cambridge dictionary

Comment: The answer is no, you don't have to. When you ask 'why not?', it assumes there is a  reason to think that you **do** have to. So, what is your reason?

Comment: **The** would be required if you were comparing her with others, as in: **She looks the best of the candidates**.

Answer (score 1):

> She looks best in bright, vibrant colors, like red and pink

means "she looks better in those colors than when wearing any other."

> She looks the best in bright, vibrant colors, like red and pink

means "she is the best-looking member [of an unspecified group] while wearing those colors."